# How to pass class-based view data to django formset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a formset that is rendered using a class-based view. I have read the django documentation and seen some answers related to this but i can't get it to work.

I get a 404 error when `project_id = kwargs.pop('project_id',None)` in the `def get_context_data` function below.

The formset doesn't render at all when `project_id = kwargs.pop('project_id',None)` in the `def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs)` function below.

`project_id` is the auto-generated `id` in the `ProjectDetails` model.

How can get `project_id` to be passed to the formset?

```
models.py
class ProjectDetails(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50,blank = False)
    client = models.CharField(max_length = 200,blank = False)
    

class ProjectFinance(models.Model):
    project_name  = models.ForeignKey(ProjectDetails,on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = 
    True,blank=False)
    finance_item = models.CharField(max_length = 50,null=True,blank=False)


forms.py
class FinanceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        project_id = kwargs.pop('project_id',None)
        super(FinanceForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    class Meta:
    model = ProjectFinance
    fields = '__all__'


FinanceFormSet= inlineformset_factory(ProjectDetails, ProjectFinance, form=FianceForm, fields='__all__',extra=2)


views.py
class FinanceView(CreateView):
    
        template_name = "project.html"
        model = ProjectFinance
        form_class = FinanceForm
    
        def get_form_kwargs(self,*args, **kwargs):
             form_kwargs = super(FinanceView, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
             form_kwargs['project_id'] = self.kwargs.get('project_id')

             return form_kwargs
    

        def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
            project_id = kwargs.pop('project_id',None)
            project = get_object_or_404(ProjectDetails,id=project_id)
            formset = FinanceFormSet(instance=project)
            context = super(FinanceView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['project'] = project
       
            return context
```

Thanks.

Comment: Consult Classy CBVs? https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/

Comment: Django's class based views weren't designed to use formsets, I would avoid trying to do that. You could look at [`django-extra-views`](https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/formset-views.html) which comes with views for formsets.

Comment: If `project_id` is coming from the URL, then use `self.kwargs` in `get_context_data`: `project_id = self.kwargs.['project_id']`. Don't use `pop()` with a default unless the key is optional.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks,using `project_id = self.kwargs.['project_id']` helped. I will also try using `django-extra-views`